# How to get the data in SQLite with "LEFT ON"

Tags: mysql, sqlite, left-join

```
SELECT CaseFolder.CaseId, CaseFolder.CaseCoverImageFileName,
            CaseFolder.CaseName, count(Event.CaseId), CaseFolder.CaseColor,
            CaseFolder.IsMedicalCase, CaseFolder.StartDate, CaseFolder.EndDate
    FROM CaseFolder
    LEFT JOIN Event ON CaseFolder.CaseId = Event.CaseId
    WHERE Event.PersonId = 1 AND Event.IsDeleted = 0 AND CaseFolder.IsDeleted = 0
    GROUP BY CaseFolder.CaseId
```

I select `Count` by table`Event` and another by table `CaseFolder`.The `primary key` is `CaseId`,But I need to select data that is included in a table but not in another table,when must add "where" with "LEFT ON".If I delete the sql code`WHERE Event.PersonId = 1 AND Event.IsDeleted = 0 AND CaseFolder.IsDeleted = 0` the result is right.Because the `WHERE` contains conditions that can't suit in table`CaseFolder`.what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on the second table in a `left join` should go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT CaseFolder.CaseId, CaseFolder.CaseCoverImageFileName,
       CaseFolder.CaseName, count(Event.CaseId), CaseFolder.CaseColor,
       CaseFolder.IsMedicalCase, CaseFolder.StartDate, CaseFolder.EndDate
FROM CaseFolder LEFT JOIN
     Event
     ON CaseFolder.CaseId = Event.CaseId AND
        Event.PersonId = 1 AND Event.IsDeleted = 0 
WHERE CaseFolder.IsDeleted = 0;
GROUP BY CaseFolder.CaseId ;
```

Otherwise, the `LEFT JOIN` turns into an `INNER JOIN`, because the condition fails with a `NULL` value.  Note, your query is easier to write and to read with table aliases:

```
SELECT cf.CaseId, cf.CaseCoverImageFileName,
       cf.CaseName, count(e.CaseId), cf.CaseColor,
       cf.IsMedicalCase, cf.StartDate, cf.EndDate
FROM CaseFolder cf LEFT JOIN
     Event e
     ON cf.CaseId = e.CaseId AND
        e.PersonId = 1 AND e.IsDeleted = 0 
WHERE cf.IsDeleted = 0;
GROUP BY cf.CaseId ;
```